# issue in loading Model using PyTorch in google-collaboratory

Tags: pytorch, google-colaboratory

I am trying to Load the Model in google_collaboratory to get evaluate it and generate all the statistics results.

**My trying**

```
import torch
import torch.nn.functional as F
import torch.optim as optim
import torch.backends.cudnn as cudnn
import torch.backends.cudnn as cudnn
import numpy as np
import torch.nn as nn
import os

def load_checkpoint(filepath):
    checkpoint = torch.load(filepath)
    model = fc_model.Network(checkpoint['input_size'],
                             checkpoint['output_size'],
                             checkpoint['hidden_layers'])
    model.load_state_dict(checkpoint['state_dict'])
    
    return model

PATH = "/content/gdrive/MyDrive/best.pt"
state_dict = load_checkpoint(PATH)
```

**The Error**

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-24-0515f2edfa1a> in <module>()
     18 
     19 PATH = "/content/gdrive/MyDrive/best.pt"
---> 20 state_dict = load_checkpoint(PATH)

2 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/torch/serialization.py in _load(zip_file, map_location, pickle_module, pickle_file, **pickle_load_args)
    849     unpickler = pickle_module.Unpickler(data_file, **pickle_load_args)
    850     unpickler.persistent_load = persistent_load
--> 851     result = unpickler.load()
    852 
    853     torch._utils._validate_loaded_sparse_tensors()

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'models'

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NOTE: If your import is failing due to a missing package, you can
manually install dependencies using either !pip or !apt.

To view examples of installing some common dependencies, click the
"Open Examples" button below.
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I tried to install some library but it gives me the same is there anyways to load models inside google collaboratory.

Answer (score 1):

This problem is that when you save the weight you actually uses `torch.save(model` instead of `model.state_dict()`

One way to solve this is import the `models` "the same way you did when train". This is important as when you save the whole model it save the name reference along with the weight.

Maybe you'll need to upload it if `models` is a file. If it's an object then just put it to a cell and it'll work.